# Image not saving in correct place Php

Tags: php, image-uploading, filepath

This is my folder layout on the server: http://gyazo.com/1331ac0aaaa444bdedad9e91a6dfe23d

[image]

I am trying to save an image into the "1" folder.

```
move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Backend/Sets/".$desired_dir."/".$file_tmp);
```

That is the line I am using to try to move the file I have uploaded.

I printed out the $SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] and it ends with "/hub" - which you can see in my screen shot.

The issue is that my image in saving inside the /Backend folder and not going further into the /Sets/1 folders.

All of my .php files are in the /Backend folder. So that may have something to do with it. I am really unsure. 
Thanks,
Waq

EDIT:

Here is the block of code that I have changed it to on suggestion from another thread:

```
if(empty($errors)==true){
print("desired dir = ".$desired_dir);

if(is_dir("Sets/".$desired_dir)==false){
mkdir("Sets/".$desired_dir, 0700);
}

if(is_file("Sets/".$desired_dir."/".$Title)==false){
rename ($file_tmp,$Title);
move_uploaded_file($Title,"/Sets/$desired_dir/$Title");
```

I have made sure desired_dir = 1.

Still the same problem however.

Comment: i expect its  actully failing and your not seeing the error message. Perhas error reporting\display are off, turn them on `error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Try to echo the path `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Backen....`

Comment: What is the value of $desired_dir? Is it `"1"`? Maybe it's empty?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. I turned on errors, but no errors were reported when i re ran it. And I made sure that desired_dir was 1. I have since changed my code and removed DOCUMENT ROOT after another thread suggested i dont need it. Still putting it in the same place though.

Answer (score 0):

Add some error checking:

```
$sets = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/Backend/Sets/".$desired_dir."/";
if (!is_dir($sets))
  throw new Exception("Not a folder: " . $sets);

move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $sets . $file_tmp);
```

In this way you have a clearer picture of what's going on